# External Hdd adaptor can be used on any hdd?

Tags: hardware, hard-drive

I want to buy a **Seagate Backup Plus** external HDD. It comes with an adaptor which is really useful as you can get the adapter down and just put in like an internal Sata HDD, and with the adapter on you can connect it via USB.

Now, my question is if I could use the adapter on any internal hdd so that I will be able to acces it via USB?

From what I've seen this should be possible as it has just the standard Sata and alimentation cable slots but I'm not that good with hardware and would like a second opinion from others who are willing to help before I buy it.

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: We are talking about the portable edition.

Comment: Sorry - totally off-topic - this is a **programming** Q&A site - not a hardware forum ... try [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com) instead.

Comment: @marc_s You are right no problem. This was intended for Super User but I missread this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57998/hardware-questions-and-stack-exchange Voted to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you could use that cable on any internal HDD.

With that said you could however get something similar to this which will in fact allow you to use most internal HDD via USB:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812232002&name=Adapters-Gender-Changers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work with any SATA HDD and even with SSD if required.

If it is a laptop drive it should be also fine: https://superuser.com/questions/226481/connect-a-2-5-laptop-hard-disk-sata-hard-disk-to-desktop-pc